# What is the difference between objectid(), hash(), pointer_from_obj() and pointer() in Julia?

Tags: julia

What is the difference between `objectid()`, `hash()`, `pointer()` and `pointer_from_objref()` in Julia?

What is the operator that compares with `===` ?

```
julia> L1 = [1,2,3];

julia> L2 = L1;

julia> L3 = copy(L1);

julia> objectid(L1), objectid(L2), objectid(L3)
(0xac55c2b098913d98, 0xac55c2b098913d98, 0xbdee7946bbc068f0)

julia> hash(L1), hash(L2), hash(L3)
(0xecc5186e7be222c6, 0xecc5186e7be222c6, 0xecc5186e7be222c6)

julia> pointer_from_objref(L1), pointer_from_objref(L2), pointer_from_objref(L3)
(Ptr{Nothing} @0x00007f6888141e40, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00007f6888141e40, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00007f68881438f0)

julia> pointer(L1), pointer(L2), pointer(L3)
(Ptr{Int64} @0x00007f6888141e80, Ptr{Int64} @0x00007f6888141e80, Ptr{Int64} @0x00007f6888143930)
```

From the documentation:

```
objectid(x)                                                                                
Get a hash value for x based on object identity. objectid(x)==objectid(y) if x === y.      

hash(x[, h::UInt])                                                                         
Compute an integer hash code such that isequal(x,y) implies hash(x)==hash(y).              

pointer_from_objref(x)
Get the memory address of a Julia object as a Ptr.

pointer(array [, index])
Get the native address of an array or string, optionally at a given location index.
```

Comment: What does the documentation say? After reading the documentation, which question(s) remain? Expand these questions in detail, in regards to the documentation read.

Comment: That is why I am asking, because I did not understand the documentation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `pointer` works on arrays and strings and `pointer(x)` returns `Ptr{X}` where `X` is a type stored in `x` (a corner case is standard strings in base where it is `UInt8` although `eltype` of `String` is `Char`). This gives you a pointer where **data** is stored; two different objects can have the pointer compare with `==` as true, e.g. with `x=[1]` and `y=reinterpret(UInt8, x)` you will get `pointer(x) == pointer(y)` (although those pointers have different types);
- `pointer_from_objref` works on any **mutable** object and returns `Ptr{Nothing}`. For arrays and strings this is not the same as `pointer` because arrays/strings also have some metadata that is stored before the actual data.
- `objectid` - as the documentation says is a hash that is based on the rule that if two objects `x` and `y` have a property that `x===y` is true then they should have the same `objectid` (the actual implementation is a bit complex to cover the `x===y` rule correctly - for instance `s1 = "12"` and `s2 = "12"` will most likely have a different value returned by `pointer` but since `s1 === s2` then `objectid` will return the same value on them;
- `hash` is a *standard* hash value that is based on `isequal` not on `===`. This means e.g. that two arrays `x=[1]` and `y=[1]` will have the same hash (as they have the same contents and compare as equal using `isequal`) but have different `objectid` because they are not identical when compared using `===`
- `===` means a comparison testing if objects passed to it are *undistinguishable*. The simple rule to use in most cases is that it is:

  - objects have the same values for immutable objects
  - objects have the same memory location for mutable objects

(the last rule is a bit tricky as e.g. two strings `s1="12"` and `s2="12"` compare as equal using `===` because they are immutable, but actually they are *distinguishable* using `pointer` function)

So as you can see the rules are a bit complex to ensure that in common cases users get what they expect.

Comment: Thank you very much! A lot of useful information. By the way, where did you learn it? The official documentation is not that helpful...

Comment: In the end you need to read the source code in case of doubt. Fortunately most of it is in Julia.